# what Solidity, solc, web3.js, Ganache versions combination is currently working

Tags: solidity, web3js, ganache

What combination of the latest versions of Solidity, solc, web3.js and Ganache is really working at the moment?

I'm trying to use the following:

Solidity ˆ0.8.0

solc ˆ0.8.9

web3.js ˆ1.6.0

ganache-cli ˆ6.1.8

The problem is:

I call a really primitive function to read a public value in my smart contract and I get this error:
"VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode"

I googled and haven't found a working solution. Some answers suggested to change the version of Ganache, that's why I'm trying to find a 'happy' combination of the latest versions.

Maybe, not the latest versions but the ones really working without substantial problems. Have you got any success with it?

Answer (score 0):

Needed to update the version of Ganache to 6.5.0 or higher. This solves the problem.